# "An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Error while copying content to a stream" in TFS build log

Tags: tfsbuild, build-automation

We recently upgraded our TFS Server from 2010 to 2015. The build definitions from TFS 2010 were also updated so that they were compatible with the new TFS 2015.

Once a build is finished we see the following error in build logs / summary :-

> An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop
>   location. Details: Error while copying content to a stream.

This was never an issue with the old TFS server. We also found that the **build output is not copied to the drop location**.

I've already checked the permissions, sharing etc. and everything seems correct.

Not sure if this is related but on running the build in diagnostic mode, we also got the following error:-

> Build **** (vstfs:///Build/Build/***) did not provide
>   'logs\ActivityLog.AgentScope.14.xml'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can remote to tfs server, and access drop location from that computer?

Comment: @Claudius yes, that drop location is accessible from tfs server

Comment: I know you mentioned it but to be sure you can open build templates in vs 2015 and it shows no errors? And do any builds pass?

Comment: @Claudius There are no errors in the build template. All builds succeed partially(due to this error). Everything is deployed correctly as well. Just to mentions that the build definitions are not vNext based. The template are XAML build template.

Comment: If you create a new build definition to queue a build, could you reproduce this issue? If you copy build output to server, will you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the build controller account have R/W permissions on the drop location.

Then, try to pass the parameter `/flp:verbosity="Diagnostic"` in the MSBuild arguments section, of the Process tab, in the build definition.

Comment: The permissions are already present & Diagnostic parameter returns nothing unusual.

Comment: If you create a new build definition to queue a build, could you reproduce this issue? If you copy build output to server, will you get this error?

Comment: Do you mean creating a new vNext build?

Comment: No, create a new XAML build definition.

Comment: I tried this and got a different error this time around. "An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: An error occurred while sending the request." However, the build outputs were copied to the drop folder.

Comment: Did you use the default process template in TFS 2015? Also, if you copy build output to server, will you get any error?